# column "scopes" does not exist when using Loopback 3.8.0

Tags: loopback

I hit a weird problem where it said `column "scopes" does not exist`.  Here is the log I encountered in server but not in local enviroment:

```
Unhandled error for request GET /api/continents?access_token=aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbL1AwzSoH8eHXwPdjzQATRXqto3lngEokVxR2j: error: column "scopes" does not exist
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642201+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:569:11)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642202+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:396:17)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642203+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:132:22)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642204+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642209+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642210+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642210+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
2017-05-05T04:35:06.642211+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

All APIs involving access token failed for same reason.  If access token is not set, the APIs work as expected (if public, I got data; if authentication required, I got 401/403).

I tried local - it works, I tried `heroku local` - it works too.  After a long testing, I found that the differences (and verified) is both my local and `heroku local` are running loopback version 3.4.0 while my servers are running 3.8.0.

After I enforce the server to use 3.4.0, it is normal.

Digging into `/node_modules/loopback/common/models/access-token.json`, here are the differences between 3.4.0 and 3.8.0:

Loopback 3.4.0:

```
"name": "AccessToken",
"properties": {
  "id": { "type": "string", "id": true },
  "ttl": { "type": "number", "ttl": true, "default": 1209600, "description": "time to live in seconds (2 weeks by default)" },
  "created": { "type": "Date", "defaultFn": "now" }
},
```

Loopback 3.8.0:

```
"name": "AccessToken",
"properties": {
  "id": { "type": "string", "id": true },
  "ttl": { "type": "number", "ttl": true, "default": 1209600, "description": "time to live in seconds (2 weeks by default)" },
  "scopes": {
    "type": ["string"],
    "description": "Array of scopes granted to this access token."
  },
  "created": { "type": "Date", "defaultFn": "now" }
},
```

Since I didn't checkin the node_modules, does anyone know how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue from upgrading to Loopback v3.8.

You can remedy the issue by autoupdating the AccessToken table using a script. Here is a basic version of an autoupdate script.

```js
var path = require('path');

var app     = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/server'));
var ds      = app.datasources.db;

function update() {
  // migrate AccessToken
  ds.autoupdate('AccessToken', function (err) {
    console.log("ds.autoupdate('AccessToken', err=", err)
    if (err) throw err;

    ds.disconnect();

  }); // autoupdate('AccessToken')
}

// console.log("ds=", ds)
console.log("ds.connected=", ds.connected)
if(ds.connected) {
// Run autoupdate
  update();
} else {
  ds.once('connected', function() {
    // Run autoupdate
    update();
  });
}
```

You can run this by naming it autoupdate.js, putting it in the root of the server directory and then run in the console `node autoupdate.js`

Then you will be golden.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same trouble moving from lb2.x to lb3.17.0

just did an alter table :
ALTER TABLE accesstoken ADD scopes TEXT;